# Why would secret diplomacy between two different dimensions be necessary?

Tags: society, government, politics, geopolitics, diplomacy

I am writing a book with two dimensions populated by human beings, one of which is our own. Only a small number of people in both dimensions know about the existence of the other. Governments in both dimensions do not know about the other.

Our dimension (known as Anvilu) is more technologically advanced in some ways compared to the other (known as Adhiku). Residents of Anvilu have advanced personal computers that residents of Adhiku do not. On the other hand, residents of Anvilu possess various forms of technology such as extremely high speed rail that residents of Adhiku do not have.

However, there exists an organization between both worlds that operates as a secret society. This organization contains a portal between the two dimensions to allow the two civilizations to contact each other.

The institution controls the only known portal between the worlds. There could be other portals in other parts of the world, but we do not know of anything.

This institution functions like an embassy, performing diplomatic work between the two dimensions. It keeps each other up to date on the latest information between the worlds. It recruits capable individuals to work there.

Why would diplomacy between the two different dimensions be necessary? What benefit (other than keeping the portal safe) could residents of both dimensions get in contact? Technology, culture, and religion from the different dimensions is **not** shared between the two.

**Edit:** I changed "embassy" to "organization" after one user pointed out that the definition of the word embassy demands that it is government-sponsored.

**Edit 2:** I made this question a lot more specific to comply with community guidelines.

Comment: [*Counterpart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterpart_(TV_series)), two seasons (2017-2018), 20 episodes. Highly recommended. (And it fulfills the exact requirements of the question. In the show, the two parallel dimensions split at a certain point during the Cold War, and the inter-dimensional border-crossing is located in the former Stasi building in East Berlin. It's a German show, so that the formalities of crossing between the dimensions are showed with love and attention to detail.)

Comment: Does "contact" mean information-only? Or are there vicious red aliens walking freely among us?

Comment: Does the organisation control the only portal / only possible portal between the two dimensions?  Very different situation if there are or could be other portals.  What is the level of technological and social development on each side?  (Apparently one side is "us", but is it current, future or past "us")

Comment: VTC:NDC. We need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609). Please explain the governing, legal, and economic structure supporting this organization (no org exists without these things, even secret orgs). Please provide examples of what interdimensional visits accomplish. Please explain its authority (not its purpose, but what rules it has and how it enforces them). Specifically, how will you judge a best answer?

Comment: Whereas it seems to me that you're asking us to write a key element in your story for you. VTC: Story Based. If you were to define the relationship between dimensions, the source of tension as it were, then we might be able to answer as then we'd have worldbuilding context, but you seem to be asking us to decide that for you, which is story-based.

Comment: didn't you answer your own question? "This organization contains a portal between the two dimensions to allow the two civilizations to contact each other."

Comment: Thank you for the edits, but this is still too broad. Please explain how you will judge a best answer? Raw "fishing-for-ideas" questions don't work well on SE. Diplomacy exists for basically two purposes: to negotiate trade and to avert (or manage) war. Without knowing what the portal is used for, we really can't offer insight into why the org would need to exist. How would you judge between an answer like the Men In Black organization vs. Harry Potter's Ministry of Magic?

Answer (score 2):

#### Arbitrage

The two worlds are not identical, and goods have differing prices between the two dimensions.

Your secret society buys goods in one market and sells them in the other, slowly building up their wealth in both dimensions' currencies.

Secret societies need lots of dark money to survive. This is their main income.

Answer (score 1):

There are already a few examples of this in film and TV. As AlexP mentions in the comments, [Counterpart](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4643084) matches your question fairly well. Another example that springs to mind is [Fringe](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1119644), which also has cooperation between two universes. The idea is also touched on in various SF shows like Stargate (and Stargate: Atlantis) where the primary universe has occasional contact with people - usually alternate versions of the main characters - from alternate realities. [The Flash](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3107288) has a lot of interactions with multi-universal groups, including the Council of Wells and the Collectors.

On the question itself, the reasons for the existence of such an organisation is dependent on the situation the universes exist in.

In Fringe the primary purpose is to prevent people from travelling between the two worlds since the methods used to do so are damaging both universes, which will ultimately result in the destruction of one or both of the universes. Each side is trying to ensure that either this does not happen, or that if it does then their universe is the one to survive.

In The Flash, the Collectors are a group of bounty hunters who track universe-hopping criminals (most of the time) to bring them back to face trial in their home universe. The Council of Wells on the other hand are a group of alternates of the same person who collaborate occasionally to share information. Various other groups hop universes for any number of reasons, including Barry going all over the multiverse seemingly at random.

And so on.

In other words, every group will have its own reason to do what they do. Maybe they're protecting their universe. Maybe they're trying to dominate the other universe. Maybe they want to trade for materials or technology that only the other side has. Maybe they just secretly like being the only ones who even know that the other side exists, and all they're doing is keeping anyone else from finding out.

In order to give you a solid reason for this I'd have to create your setting for you. Then it would be my setting, and you can't play in my setting. It's mine.

Answer (score 1):

In order for those two dimensions to engage in diplomacy, you need some form of peaceful interaction between them. Peaceful interaction requires that both dimensions **want something the other dimension can provide**.

If both sides want something the other side has in abundance, then they could engage in trade. If one side has something they don't want to part with voluntarily, then you have a conflict.

Diplomacy is needed to arbitrate both trade and conflict.

When the connection between both dimensions is first discovered, then there would be a need to do some research to find out what the other dimension has that could be interesting. You already said that there should be no exchange of technology or religion. But what about natural resources? Living space? Workforce? Waste disposal? Culture? Tourism destinations? Or research just for curiosities sake? Diplomacy would be required to negotiate what information the two dimensions are willing to share about themselves and the conditions under which expedition parties of one dimension may visit the other.

Then, when both dimensions have a clear picture of what the other has to offer and what their own dimension can offer in return, then it's time to negotiate under which terms those exchanges could take place. Visitors would be expected to follow certain rules which need to be negotiated. And if those rules are violated, there need to be negotiations about what the consequences will be. This will again keep diplomats busy.

Note that diplomacy will only work as long as there is at least some balance of power which makes a peaceful solution more viable than a violent solution. If either side finds out (or believes) that they are vastly superior to the other and can just take what they want, then they will likely just invade. As Carl von Clausewitz said: *"War is the continuation of diplomacy with other means"*. You said you want the existence of the other dimension to be a secret, so that could be a shadow war conducted by secret agents. The superior side might in that case still pretend to be interested in diplomacy, because that will give them more opportunities to obtain information and plant agents under the cover of diplomatic missions.

When the war is over, then the diplomats will be required to draft the terms of surrender and then convince the losing side that it is in their best interest to stick to them. Sure, they could enslave the whole population, but slavery can be inefficient. It might be far more useful to keep the power structures of the losing side intact, but under tight control (which also fits the aforementioned "shadow war" theme). That means that diplomats will be required to regularly talk to the leaders of the subjugated. They need to keep them convinced that doing as they are told is in their best interest. Meanwhile the subjugated will try to convince the diplomats that granting them more autonomy will benefit both sides.